# Passing indexes of associative array to functions as arguments

Tags: php, function, parameter-passing, associative-array

I am working with associative arrays and passing indexes as arguments in a function. If I try to pass them as arguments and use "print_r", the function outputs the array values and all of it's indexes with no problems, i can even call store the values of these indexes into variables and output them in the browser.

my problem is if i try to code it like this:

```
$arr_specimen[$sel_ind1]
```

the browser shows an error of undefined index even though it previously outputs the indexes and its values. What is the possible explanation for this error and how can I correct this error? here is my code:

```
function array_picker($sel_ind1, $sel_ind2, $sel_ind3, $arr_specimen)
{
    print "$sel_ind1 <br>";
    print "$sel_ind2 <br>";
    print "$sel_ind3 <br>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr_specimen);
    echo "</pre>";
}




$selection = array(
    array('fruit' => 'apple', 'normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'orange', 'normal_price' => 4.15, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'grapes', 'normal_price' => 8.35, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'mango', 'normal_price' => 6.65, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'peach', 'normal_price' => 5.45, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'melon', 'normal_price' => 9.05, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'pomegranate', 'normal_price' => 7.95, 'status' => 'discounted')
);

 array_picker('fruit', 'normal_price', 'status', $selection);
```

Comment: You have multiple arrays in `$selection`, which one do you want, apple, orange, grapes, etc?  What do you want the output to be?

Comment: i want to create a function that will get all the fruits with 'discounted' value as status and store them into a new array which will present all the discounted fruits with the same index format as 'fruit', 'normal_price', 'status'

Answer (score 0):

Accessing `$arr_specimen[$sel_ind1]` as shown in your code will access the index `'fruit'` in `$arr_specimen`, which is `$selection` below. `$selection` is not an associative array, therefore does not have the index `'fruit'`. You need to access the second dimension of arrays like the following: `$arr_specimen[0][$sel_ind1]`, `$arr_specimen[1][$sel_ind1]`. Take a look at the modified code below.

```
function array_picker($sel_ind1, $sel_ind2, $sel_ind3, $arr_specimen)
{
    print "$sel_ind1 <br>";
    print "$sel_ind2 <br>";
    print "$sel_ind3 <br>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr_specimen[0][$sel_ind1]); //will get fruit index from first array
    print_r($arr_specimen[1][$sel_ind2]); //will get price index from second array...
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @AbraCadaver alluded to, you are trying to access the `fruit` element of an integer-index array (not an associative array).

```
// your current array
$selection = array(
    array('fruit' => 'apple', 'normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'orange', 'normal_price' => 4.15, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'grapes', 'normal_price' => 8.35, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'mango', 'normal_price' => 6.65, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'peach', 'normal_price' => 5.45, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'kiwi', 'normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'melon', 'normal_price' => 9.05, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    array('fruit' => 'pomegranate', 'normal_price' => 7.95, 'status' => 'discounted')
);



// to do what you imply by your code
$selection = array(
    'apple'=>array('normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    'orange'=>array('normal_price' => 4.15, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    'grapes'=>array('normal_price' => 8.35, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    'mango'=>array('normal_price' => 6.65, 'status' => 'discounted'),
    'peach'=>array('normal_price' => 5.45, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    'kiwi'=>array('normal_price' => 3.75, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    'melon'=>array('normal_price' => 9.05, 'status' => 'non-discounted'),
    'pomegranate'=>array('normal_price' => 7.95, 'status' => 'discounted')
);

function array_picker($fruit, $sel_ind2, $sel_ind3, $arr_specimen)
{
    print "{$arr_specimen[$fruit][$sel_ind2]} <br>";
    print "{$arr_specimen[$fruit][$sel_ind3]} <br>";

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arr_specimen);
    echo "</pre>";
}

array_picker('apple', 'normal_price', 'status', $selection);
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I now know that what I created is just a multidimensional array not an associative one. thanks for enlightening me

Comment: I can finally work on my desired output based on the inputs given to me. Thank you very much for the help.